# How can I convert a list of maps into a map of sets in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In Python, I have the following list of maps:

```
[{'CN': 'SC',
  'LB': 'g1k',
  'SM': 'HG1'},
 {'CN': 'SC',
  'LB': 'g2k',
  'SM': 'HG2'},
 {'CN': 'SC',
  'LB': 'g3k',
  'SM': 'HG3'}]
```

and I would like to obtain a map like this:

```
{ 'CN' : 'SC',
  'LB' : ['g1k', 'g2k', 'g3k'],
  'SM' : ['HG1', 'HG2', 'HG3']
}
```

What is the most pythonic way to do this?
Thanks!

p.s. Further, I intend to convert the new structure of data to JSON in order to be displayed in a web page.

Comment: Note that your desired output is a little unpythonic itself: unless there's a pretty good reason, you shouldn't have one value in a dict be a string and the others be lists of strings.  This is particularly true here because strings are iterable, so iterating over a value would work for `"LB"` and `"SM"` but in the `"SC"` case it'd be iterating over the characters `"S"` and `"C"`, and `len()` would return 2, not 1, which probably isn't what's intended.

Comment: I agree that my output may look non-pythonic, but what I want to do further is to send this map as json to a web page. And I wouldn't want to display things like 'CN':'SC' 3 times. Plus I want to have them grouped by categories.

Comment: that is why all the answers use `sets` instead of `lists`

Comment: yes, good observation - I corrected the title of the question.

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke: I think the OP would have to convert back into lists anyhow for serialization purposes though -- I don't think JSON has a set type.

Comment: I've added the conversion back to lists to my answer after reading the comment about `JSON`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> list_of_map = [{'CN': 'SC',
...   'LB': 'g1k',
...   'SM': 'HG1'},
...  {'CN': 'SC',
...   'LB': 'g2k',
...   'SM': 'HG2'},
...  {'CN': 'SC',
...   'LB': 'g3k',
...   'SM': 'HG3'}]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(set)
>>> for map in list_of_map:
...     for k,v in map.items():
...         d[k].add(v)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'LB': set(['g3k', 'g1k', 'g2k']), 'CN': set(['SC']), 'SM': set(['HG2', 'HG3', 'HG1'])})
```

This isn't quite the data structure you wanted, but it's pretty close and would be easy to change over if you really needed to.  (I haven't shown it here though as I think that `set`s are the way to go here instead of `list`s).

To get back to lists:

```
>>> back_to_lists = {k:list(v) for k,v in d.items()}
>>> back_to_lists
{'LB': ['g3k', 'g1k', 'g2k'], 'CN': ['SC'], 'SM': ['HG2', 'HG3', 'HG1']}
```

Or even:

```
>>> back_to_lists = {k:sorted(v) for k,v in d.items()}
>>> back_to_lists
{'LB': ['g1k', 'g2k', 'g3k'], 'CN': ['SC'], 'SM': ['HG1', 'HG2', 'HG3']}
```

Comment: Silly question: though this might be the only way of doing this, isn't it a bit inefficient to copy everything to sets and then from sets back to lists? (in case I have large sets/lists)

Comment: @Clara -- It's a bit inefficient in terms of memory, but in terms of computation, it's probably the fastest way to do it.  Keeping everything as lists is going to kill your performance because checking if an object is already in the list takes an O(N) time (where N is the length of the list).  Compared to a set which takes O(1) time.  Converting things back to a list happens quite quickly and easily too -- It's a simple iteration which is O(N), but it's only done once.

Comment: Ah, good point!! Forgot about the overhead cause by the search that precedes the insertion in a list. Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [21]: nk=[{'CN': 'SC', 'LB': 'g1k', 'SM': 'HG1'},
    ...:  {'CN': 'SC', 'LB': 'g2k', 'SM': 'HG2'},
    ...:  {'CN': 'SC', 'LB': 'g3k', 'SM': 'HG3'}]

In [22]: result={}

In [23]: for x in nk:
    ...:     for k in x:
    ...:         result.setdefault(k,set()).add(x[k])
    ...:         

In [24]: result
Out[24]: 
{'CN': set(['SC']),
 'LB': set(['g3k', 'g1k', 'g2k']),
 'SM': set(['HG2', 'HG3', 'HG1'])}
```

or

```
In [60]: nk=[{'CN': 'SC', 'LB': 'g1k', 'SM': 'HG1'},
    ...:  {'CN': 'SC', 'LB': 'g2k', 'SM': 'HG2'},
    ...:  {'CN': 'SC', 'LB': 'g3k', 'SM': 'HG3'}]

In [61]: {z[0][0]:set(z[1]) for z in [zip(*x) for x in zip(*[y.items() for y in [x for x in nk]])]}
Out[61]: 
{'CN': set(['SC']),
 'LB': set(['g3k', 'g1k', 'g2k']),
 'SM': set(['HG2', 'HG3', 'HG1'])}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order in the values of the new dict doesn't matter, you can do:

```
In [1]: maps = [{'CN': 'SC',
   ...:   'LB': 'g1k',
   ...:   'SM': 'HG1'},
   ...:  {'CN': 'SC',
   ...:   'LB': 'g2k',
   ...:   'SM': 'HG2'},
   ...:  {'CN': 'SC',
   ...:   'LB': 'g3k',
   ...:  

In [2]: from itertools import chain

In [3]: {k: set(m[k] for m in maps if k in m) for k in chain.from_iterable(maps)}
Out[3]: 
{'CN': set(['SC']),
 'LB': set(['g2k', 'g1k', 'g3k']),
 'SM': set(['HG3', 'HG2', 'HG1'])}
```

Comment: As a side note, `chain(*maps)` could be `chain.from_iterable(maps)` which avoids resolving `maps` into a tuple and allows it to remain in it's lazy state.

Comment: If the order *does* matter, and the keys are always the same (pretty stringent requirement, admittedly), I was thinking of `d2 = {k: [m[k] for m in list_of_map] for k in list_of_map[0]}` or something.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for the `chain` advice, I'm a little puzzled by your first comment though. Do you mean that my answer duplicates yours?

Comment: @LevLevitsky -- No ... I meant that I was having a hard time understanding it -- Don't take any offense though, I always have a hard time with nested comprehensions.

Comment: @mgilson Ah, okay then. This time it seemed natural to me to use one: that's the order I was thinking in.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go for the unwrapped, not clever, loopy option..

where d is your list of dicts, and md is an empty dict

```
for d in dicts:
 for k in d:
  if k in md:
   md[k].add(d[k])
  else:
   md[k]=set([d[k]])
```